# iphone and ipad issue - white space at the bottom of the bootstrap cards

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, bootstrap-4, whitespace

I used bootstrap cards. They look likes good in browsers and android device but in ipad and iphone they have issue. Card's height grows and white space appears at bottom of the cards.
You can check 2 screenshots to see issue.
[Screenshot of iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP9eY.png)

[Screenshot of Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYYCD.png)

```
<div class="row" id="cardview">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xxl-4">
    <div class="card card-custom gutter-b card-stretch">
        <div class="card-body">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.card.card-custom.card-stretch {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-align: stretch !important;
-ms-flex-align: stretch !important;
align-items: stretch !important;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
```

}

Comment: What's in `card-stretch`? Perhaps handy to also include your custom CSS to this question.

Comment: I added detail of css class. That's right. Issue is related to card-stretch ,It should show scroll bar but it causes white space at button and I don't now how I can fix it. This css class is bootstrap class.